# What is the way to org data read from a file in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, file, c#-4.0, console-application

There are some cool classes and tricks and short cuts in C#.  I know this but I have not worked with C# enough to have them memoried.

One cool trick is this.  If you read from a file data that is arranged in a similar line-by-line structure where each line is arranged in columns spaced out by tabs, the data can be read into a kind of class in C# and then you can parse out one column of data by simply doing a "for each" command.  Does anyone know off-hand how this is done?

Basically, what I am talking about is this.  I understand how to read a file line by line:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file =
   new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    counter++;
}

file.Close();
```

Now, how would I go about replacing `Console.WriteLine(line);` with code that will organize the data automatically into members of a class provided that the line columns in the input file are seperated by /t (tabs)?

Comment: You might like this library: http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/ for this task.

Comment: Another alternative is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx - you just need to reference the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly in your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `line.Split('\t')` This will give you `string[]` array. You can then parse each element to proper data type.

```
MyData LineToMyData(string line)
{
    try
    {
        string[] arr = line.Split('\t');

        return new MyData()
        {
            Time = DateTime.Parse(arr[0]),
            Name = arr[1],
            Age = Int32.Parse(arr[2])
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("line", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you need a class:

```
public class Stuff
{
    public string field1 {get; set;}
    public string field2 {get; set;}
    public string fieldn {get; set;}
    public Stuff()
    {
        field1 = "";
        field2 = "";
        fieldn = "";
    }
}
```

Then create a list of your new class before the While-->read.  Inside the while-->read, create your class, and fill it with the data using split as mentioned above.

```
List<Stuff> lotsaStuff = new List<Stuff>();        
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)         
{         
    string[] fields = line.Split('\t');
    Stuff newStuff = new Stuff();
    newStuff.field1 = fields[0].ToString();
    newStuff.field2 = fields[1].ToString();;
    newStuff.fieldn = fields[2].ToString();;
    lotsaStuff.Add(newStuff);         
}
```

After the file close, you can use your list:

```
foreach (Stuff mystuff in lotsaStuff)
{
    if (mystuff.field2 == "useME")
    {
        //do something here...
    }
}
```

You will want to match the data types (I used all strings for simplicity) to your data, both in the class, and when you are filling the class from the line read.